# nginx says it's stopping but doesn't actually stop

Tags: nginx, service, passenger

I installed nginx with phusion using the `passenger-install-nginx-module` installer.

This worked.  After installing and visiting my domain, I see the Welcome to nginx page.

However, the `service nginx {start|stop|restart}` commands don't work.

After a quick google search, I found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/257108/trying-to-start-nginx-on-vps-i-get-nginx-unrecognized-service

which I executed and found that the script gets executed (e.g. prints `Stopping nginx:`, but it doesn't actually stop the server, because I can still see the webpage and no status is printed such as `[ OK ]`.

How can I get the service commands for nginx to work.

Comment: Are you sure you have or Passenger added nginx as a service in Ubuntu? If you are on SSH, try reloading your bash profile again. That might help.